# Unusual VS2010 Link Error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libssh2d.lib'

Tags: visual-studio-2010, shared-libraries, libssh2, libssh

I am trying to work with [libssh2](http://www.libssh2.org/) libraries in VS2010. I am getting a weird error of `LNK1104: cannot open file 'libssh2d.lib'`. I have clearly included the libraries in the Project Properties->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories.

There are couple of other additional libraries with the one above, and they get included without an issue except this.

Also the Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies has that file name 'libssh2d.lib' specified in it.

Any inputs as to why am I still seeing that error? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just needed to add "libssh2d.lib":
Linker->Input->Additional Dependencies.
Also "Debug_lib" was added in:
Linker->General->Additional Library Directories

This resolved the issue.